# What image type should I use to store MFA ImageFieldInfo images?

Tags: yodlee

How do I know what image format type to store the image bytes as for MFA ImageFieldInfo?  The Yodlee sample app code assumes jpeg, but I've seen at least one example where the returned image was not in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SOAP call returns the image in bytes You can convert those to any image format you want. Since you have to show these images to a user to enter the MFA details hence Yodlee's sample code converts it to jpeg because jpeg files are smaller in size.

Comment: I also would like an answer to this. The answer above doesn't make sense. Yes I can turn the image into whatever format I like but I need to know what the original image is to do this. It is just bytes, but bytes have an encoding, I couldn't just turn this into a word document or a PDF as it's "just bytes". 

Without an actual mime-type in the API, all a consumer can do is try each image type until one is valid.

What are the chances of getting the mime type of the original image included in the API so that it's usable.